# Filter plugin cordova-plugin-contacts to search only on phone address book

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I have some trouble with the cordova plugin [cordova-plugin-contacts](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts).
When using the navigator.contacts.find method, the plugin searches for contacts in the phone address book AND also in the gmail account of the attached google account (using it in android).

I would like to filter the contacts, so that only the phone contacts are displayed. Otherwise the contact list can be really long and it takes too long. I tried it by using:

```
var fields = [navigator.contacts.fieldType.displayName];
```

since the contacts found in the gmail account have a null for this attribute but it didn't work.

Do you have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Edit:
It works when I use

```
options.hasPhoneNumber = true;
```

but I would like to get all the contacts of the phone's address book and not only the ones with phone number.

Comment: options.hasPhoneNumber = true; its only .Other way also relates to that .because you have to apply filter in search email equal to empty.

Comment: Agree with @Hassan Ali

Comment: Ok thanks guys, then I will go for this approach.